# Breezejs customize backingStore adapter

Tags: javascript, breeze, single-page-application

I wonder if there is an easy way to implement a cutom modelLibrary adapter similar to the native backingStore adapter.

Basically, I use the backingStore adapter since i don't want my properties to be ko observables. However, I want to add some additional customization; I would like make the date values instances of momentJS.

I just wonder if there are any extension points in the native backingStore adapter or if there is any other easier way to accomplish that task.

Comment: I can fix that by changing the breezeJS source code; But that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: The API documentation gives little hints on how to create your own if you know where to look.  I believe the key is using the getProperty and setProperty of the entities prototype and defining how to 'intercept' the values, but there is probably a lot more complexity than that.  +1 for attention.

Answer (score 1):

A came up with a few solutions:

1) Change the setProperty method

The first solution a came up with was to change the setProperty method; So basically I check if the incoming value is an instance of Date in which case I turn it into a moment instance.

```
 proto.setProperty = function (propertyName, value) {
        //if (!this._backingStore.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
        //    throw new Error("Unknown property name:" + propertyName);
        //}
        var val = value instanceof Date ? moment(value) : value;
        this[propertyName] = val;
        // allow setProperty chaining.
        return this;
    };
```

I didn't like this solution for several reasons. First of all, an additional check is performed each time a property value is set; furthermore, we can pass a string instance as the value of our date property, in which case we need to add some additional logic to determine the type of the value. Finally, we might want to add the same logic to other adapters as well, so we will end up repeating our self.

2) Override the DataType.parseDateFromServer method

The second solution was to pass a custom implementation of the DataType.parseDateFromServer method. That is, in the function where I apply several breeze configuration, I add the following lines of codes:

```
function parseDateAsMoment(source) {
    return moment(source);
}

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);    
breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer = parseDateAsMoment;
```

3) Import propertyFormatters

This is the solution that i ended u using. In essence, I extended the DataType with the registerPropFormatter method.

```
 DataType.registerPropFormatter = function(dataType, formatter) {
    switch (dataType) {
        case DataType.DateTime:
            DataType.parseDateFromServer = formatter;
            break;
        case DataType.DateTimeOffset:
            DataType.parseTimeFromServer = formatter;
            break;
        default:
    }
},
```

Basically, what this method does is, it lets us import custom formatter for any type of the supported DataTypes.

Then, while initializing breeze I can simply register my property formatters:

```
function parseDateAsMoment(source) {
    return moment(source);
}

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
breeze.DataType.registerPropFormatter(breeze.DataType.DateTime, parseDateAsMoment);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question, but unfortunately we haven't documented much in this area.  However, we do have 3 modelLibrary adapters that you review the source for already within breeze ('backingStore', 'ko', and 'backbone') and Breeze is designed so that adapters are pluggable.

The source files on GitHub are 'b000_breeze.modelLibrary.xxx' where xxx is the name of the adapter.

So my suggestion would be to create your own 'backingStoreMoment' adapter as a copy of the 'backingStoreAdapter'.  Take a look at the 'startTracking' method.  This method iterates over each property of each entity once before the entity is first 'created'. Since you have access to the metadata for each 'dataProperty' from within this method, I think it should be fairly straight forward to wrap any 'DateTime' or 'DateTimeOffset' properties as MomentJs values.

Please post back with your progress, and maybe we can add your work as yet another breeze adapter.

Comment: i posted an answer with some ideas about this issue